# Ionic Android Build Error

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm seeing these errors after fresh ionic, cordova, and JDK update installations when I do android build:

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.254 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'c:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'c:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Do you have right android API SDK version installed?

Comment: I have SDK Tooks (25.2.2), SDK Platform-Tools (24.0.3), SDK Build-tools (24.0.2), SDK Build-tools (24, 23.0.1, 22.0.1, 21.1.2, 20), then SDK Platform for 7.0; 6.0; 5.1.1; 4.4.2; 4.3.1; 4.2.2; 4.1.2; 4.0.3; 4.0; 2.2; and extras Google APIs, Support Repository, Google Repository, and USB driver.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update to JDK 8. Looks like you have the older version 7.

Try [JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

and see if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I did install it about 30 minutes ago, but I guess it's not seeing the new version?   Should I just uninstall 7 and 8, and reinstall 8?

Comment: Yes get rid of 7 and then reinstall 8. There could a conflict in the library path.

Comment: It removed most of the errors.  Thank you!  I'm seeing new errors now.  Please see OP as I'm changing it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem reinstalled SDK didn't work
removed old sdk and reinstalled SDK did't work

You need to delete the android folder form the platform folder and execute 
`ionic run android`  this will reinstall the platform automatically and build from scratch. I think the cache files are the problem so that is why I think this worked.

I hope it will also work for others.

Comment: I get an error `The provided path "/path/" is not an Android project.` after doing this.

Comment: check that in your config.xml the content is pointing to index.xtml I had the same problem once and it took me a while but I found that I had 


`<content src="../index.html"/>`
 instead of 
`<content src="index.html"/>`

remember to delete the android folder from the platform before rebuilding